# Why is the imaginary part of a simple square ignored?

Tags: complex

Function for $c \in \mathbb{C}$:

```
f[c_] := Im[c]^2
```

is the same as

```
f[c_] := c^2
```

The `Im` is just ignored. Why?

Comment: f0[c_]:=Im[c]^2
f1[c_]:=c^2
f0[3]===f1[3]
Out[]= False

Comment: I believe you are mistaken, consider a c in Reals, which implies c in Complex. The two are not the same

Comment: Could you give an example in which you claim this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are getting your definitions confused since you used the same name in both cases. Use distinct names

```
f[c_] := Im[c]^2

f[c]

(*  Im[c]^2  *)

f2[c_] := c^2

f2[c]

(*  c^2  *)

lst = {2, 3 I, 2 + 3 I};

f@lst

(*  {0, 9, 9}  *)

f2@lst

(* {4, -9, -5 + 12 I}  *)
```